# error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyBlock.BlockClass' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use a basic dll file that calculates the volume of a block and am using asp.net mvc to create the pages.

I have a form that takes the three inputs and in the controller page have this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class blockController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /block/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(BlockModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MyBlock.BlockClass newVol = new MyBlock.BlockClass(model.Length, model.Width, model.Height);
                return newVol;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The block dll takes the three values for length width and height and when I try to run it I get this error

```
Error   6   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyBlock.BlockClass' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'    c:\users\ryan\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\dad\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\blockController.cs  25  24  MvcApplication1
```

The only other code is from my view pages and can post that too if it would help with the problem as I am trying to display the result of the BlockClass.

Comment: why aren't you returning a `View`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(BlockModel model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MyBlock.BlockClass newVol = new MyBlock.BlockClass(model.Length, model.Width, model.Height);

        return View("MyBlockView", newVol);   // The view you want to pass the model too
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now how would I use that variable in the view?

Comment: When you put this at the top of the view: `@model MyBlock.BlockClass` you can then use the properties in your view like this: `@Model.Length`. The first statement  tells MVC that you pass in a variable of type MyBlock.BlockClass to the view, and so MVC knows that when you type @Model later on in the view, what type it is (note the casing of the 'm' in model: in the first statement (defining the model) it's lowercase m, when using it, it's uppercase M.